# How to post on FB page via FB application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This works fine :

```
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream')); 
try {
    $post = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Test message !'));   
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    header("Location:{$loginUrl}");
}
```

In this case, post is made on my wall by application.

But, I want to make the post on the application page by the application. 
When I change

```
$this->facebook->api('/me/feed')
```

to

```
$this->facebook->api('/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/feed')
```

, Post is made by me on the application.

So, how to make the post by the application on the application page itself i.e. on the FB page which can be created from the application.

So, I can see the posted post as "Test message" via 'application_name'.

Comment: Get an app access token or a page access token. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Answer (score 2):

you can read the doc of [Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

> 1. Authenticate the user and request the manage_pages permission
> 2. Get the list of pages the user manages (https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN)
>
>    > The response will be an array of Pages and Applications that the user manages [...]
>    >     Within each block will be a Page access token or Application access token which can be used to make requests to the Graph API.